# Reading data from COM port

Tags: serial-port, serial-communication

I have a little problem.
I try to read data from COM port and I receive "bad" data like following:

> 0
>   Fl- 1
>   i 2
>    3
>   ? 4
>   m? 5
>    6
>    7
>    8
>    9
>    10
>   ? 11
>    12
>    13
>   d 14
>   D 15

The code that open port is:

```
_port = new SerialPort(Settings.Default.COM, 9600, Parity.None, 8, StopBits.One);
_port.DataReceived += PortDataReceived;
_port.Open();
```

The code that read data is:

```
private void PortDataReceived(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e) 
{
    string s = _port.ReadExisting();
    _reportBuffer = _reportBuffer + s;
    _counter++;
    if (_counter == _messageLength)
    {
        //action
    }
}
```

Any Ideas are welcome!
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

If you're certain that the data you're receiving isn't what's being sent, it is worth double-checking the baud rate, parity setttings etc.

If everything is set up correctly, and you're still not getting the data that's being sent, use a terminal emulator to open the COM port. If you *can* see the correct data there, then the problem is with your code; if you can't, the problem is elsewhere.